# PHP pear-mail smtp not working

Tags: php, smtp, pear, pear-mail

When I try to run this code, I get a strange error I cannot find an answer to:

```
// Pear Mail Library
require_once "Mail.php";

$from = 'someone@gmail.com';
$to = 'someoneelse@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Hi!';
$body = "Hi,\n\nHow are you?";

$headers = array(
    'From' => $from,
    'To' => $to,
    'Subject' => $subject
);

$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array(
        'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
        'port' => '465',
        'auth' => true,
        'username' => 'someone@gmail.com',
        'password' => 'password'
    ));

$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
    echo('<p>' . $mail->getMessage() . '</p>');
} else {
    echo('<p>Message successfully sent!</p>');
}
```

The error is:

Failed to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465 [SMTP: Failed to connect socket: fsockopen(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465 (Unknown error) (code: -1, response: )]

I looked for an answer but could not find it anywhere. Please help.

Comment: Where is your server located?

Comment: The server is on lan

Comment: Check whether the outgoing traffic is blocked on port 465 or not. It could be easily something like this: https://wpengine.com/support/using-3rd-party-email-provider-send-mail-wordpress/

Comment: It's seems not to be blocked. (Made a server on that port with python and connected to it)

Comment: add this parameter to get more information maybe 'debug' => true

Comment: That works for me. However, I had to go in the `someone@gmail.com` and enable what Gaagle calls `less secure authentication` for the account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have the same problem and mine stopped working suddenly. My suspicion is the SSL certificates associated with my name server, or in your case your name server are expired. My hosting site has incompetent help as they have been at it for two weeks and still can't figure it out. So check the name server SSL certificates.

Comment: How do I check it? (My server is not port forwarded)

Comment: You need access via cPanel and/or WHM to look at the characteristics of your setup, if not, then you must go through technical support.

Answer (score 0):

The unknown error code of **-1** can be confusing but when it shows up on Pear Mail, then most likely you need to install **Mail** and **Mail_Mime**

```
pear install Mail Mail_Mime
```

SMTP errors, if any, will always be specifically reported. If this also happens, then install **Net_SMTP** also.